# Has there ever been a company that has called their paperboys "Media Distribution Officers"?

Tags: media

According to The Economist's article ["Too Many Chiefs"](http://www.economist.com/node/16423358), job title inflation is on the rise:

> America's International Association of Administrative Professionals—formerly the National Secretaries Association—reports that it has more than 500 job-titles under its umbrella, ranging from front-office co-ordinator to electronic-document specialist. **Paper boys are “media distribution officers”.** Binmen are “recycling officers”. Lavatory cleaners are “sanitation consultants”. Sandwich-makers at Subway have the phrase “sandwich artist” emblazoned on their lapels. Even the normally linguistically pure French have got in on the act: cleaning ladies are becoming “techniciennes de surface” (surface technicians).

Curious about paper boys becoming "media distribution officers", I wanted to do some research to find out the job duties of these "officers" and see how they differ from that of paperboys (seeing whether "job title inflation" may also be correlated with "job duties inflation" as well).

Unfortunately, I could not find any company that actually hires "media distribution officers". Instead, a Google search only reveals more news articles claiming that paper boys are now called “media distribution officers”, without providing specific evidence of it being true.

So, have paperboys ever been called “media distribution officers”?

Comment: Your linked Economist article was written in 2010.  The earliest version of this I can find is http://www.sheffieldforum.co.uk/showthread.php?t=382517 from 2008 - probably a joke

Comment: related: I was a "Vehicle Service Attendant" when I worked for Hertz - I cleaned cars and got them ready to rent again